# how to check Date range overlap in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a table name "StayRooms" ,
when user to pick up date range, I want to check the date range have overlap  any records in the table ,

I have tried below LINQ ,

```
  var overlap = _db.StayRooms.Where(x => x.tenant == LoginAccount && dormapplication.Sdate >= x.Sdate && dormapplication.Edate <= x.Edate).Select(y => y.days).FirstOrDefault();
```

but is not successful all times.

Can anyone suggest what I have missing over here ?

for example:

```
`s` and `f` represents    that have record (date range )in table
 
`a` represents the start of choice
`b` represents the end of choice





       s-----f       overlap
  -----+-----+-----  -------  
   a-b |     |        NO
   a---b     |        NO
   a-----b   |        YES
   a---------b        YES
   a-----------b      YES
       a---b |        YES
       a-----b        YES
       a-------b      YES
       | a-b |        YES
       | a---b        YES     
       | a-----b      YES     
       |     a-b      NO
       |     | a-b    NO
```

Comment: What is "temp"?

Comment: sorry , it' dormapplication.Edate  ,that mean the user edate choice

Comment: Your linq query checks for >= start date & <= end date, so in your example shouldn't the second & second from last results in your example show that there is an overlap?

Comment: You're diagram is fantastic!  Great question!

Answer (score 3):

According to your overlap overview, a date range overlaps the `s--f` date range if one of the following conditions are fulfilled:

- at least one of `a` or `b` is between `s` and `f`
  --> `a` < `f` and `b` > `s`
  --> `x.Sdate < dormapplication.Edate && x.Edate > dormapplication.Sdate`
- `a` is not later than `s`, and `b` is not earlier than `f`
  --> `a` <= `s` and `b` >= `f`
  --> `x.Sdate <= dormapplication.Sdate && x.Edate >= dormapplication.Edate`

Hence, I think you should achieve the desired filtering by substituting your original `Where` conditions

```csharp
.Where(x => 
    x.tenant == LoginAccount && 
    dormapplication.Sdate >= x.Sdate && 
    temp <= x.Edate)
```

with

```csharp
.Where(x => 
    x.tenant == LoginAccount && 
    (x.Sdate < dormapplication.Edate && x.Edate > dormapplication.Sdate ||
    x.Sdate <= dormapplication.Sdate && x.Edate >= dormapplication.Edate))
```

Note: In this approach, it is assumed that for each date range, `x.Sdate` is in fact prior to `x.Edate`. Additional checks for this logic may need to be introduced if they are not already there in your original code.

Comment: I had the same requirement a while ago and came to the same solution. +1 

Comment: I would use an edge date sometime in the past and just calculate the distance from that date, if a or b within s/f distance it fails

Comment: @MarkHomer Do you mean that when using the approach in this suggested answer, such an edge case fails? If so, may you provide example data that can produce such a failure?

Comment: @Astrid E. thanks for your reply ,but if use edit button to edit date range  ，it's will check  old date range ,how to exclude the edit record date range ?

Comment: @georgetovrea If you want to dynamically calculate valid date ranges whenever the user edits the target date range, I'd suggest that you first get all potentially applicable date ranges from the database (i.e. `_db.StayRooms.Where(x => x.tenant == LoginAccount).ToList()`), and then trigger the date range filtering whenever the user edits the target date range in the UI.